# jQuery data-theme not changing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, themeroller, jquery-mobile-themeroller

I am trying to set up my theme from themeroller, but it isn't changing a thing... I must be missing something but can't tell from the documentation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Site</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/DDBuddy.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-a">
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" class="ui-page">
    <div data-role="header" class="ui-header">
        <h1>Site</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" class="ui-body-a ui-content">
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
        <p>&copy;Site</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try loading on chrome with developer tools (ctrl+shift+j) on the tab "network" and look for missing links and files.

Comment: ariel, I don't know what was wrong, but I just decided to edit the index.html they give you when you download the swatches. It works for me. Thanks

Comment: You have to link structure style sheet which you get downloaded with your custom themes from ThemeRoller.

Comment: and remove query.mobile-1.4.0.min.css